# Seeking Premium Silk Scarf Mockup in Nature - Any Recommendations?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

I’m looking for a website that offers a premium-quality set of hanging silk scarf mockups. The setting should ideally be in nature, either on a tree or suspended in the air. I specifically need PSD files for easy design insertion, and my search has been challenging. Additionally, in the second part, I'm interested in general recommendations for websites that provide diverse sets of premium quality (free or paid) mockup sets. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
P.s. somehow hello in the beginning doesn’t appear, so had to put in the end! :)))

Comment: Voting to close because this is a [shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed).

Comment: It's unlikely you will find a PSD for this since it's so specific.  If the silk scarf you want has folds, essentially a 3D object, it would probably be better to look at using actual 3D modelling software such as Blender, because Photoshops 3D capabilities are extremely limited, plus Adobe is going to basically deprecate this functionality soon anyway. There's a Blender Stack Exchange if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

... I doubt that exists... It is pretty specific, don't you think?

What you can do is make it in Blender. It is free and has cloth simulation with physics, so it is not really hard to do.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+cloth+simulation

Once you made the scene, you can just change the texture bitmap and render again.

---

You can make a "floating" scarf, or put it on the floor, and if you render a transparent background you can add any you want in Ps.

For a hanging scarf, you could use a free branch model:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=tree+banch+model+blender

---

If you want it on hair, you could use Daz Studio and one scarf model.

https://www.daz3d.com/catalogsearch/result?q=scarf

Then you find the texture directory and change the material. (There is a chance the material projection is not necessarily a square like I am assuming your design is)